# jQuery widget initialization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a custom widget that accepts 2 parameters.  The first is a string and works great.  The second is a reference to a hidden field that isn't working correctly.  In the initialization of the widget, how can I access this value?

Here is some sample code:

```
<div class="Row">

<input type="hidden" id="HiddenField" value="ValueINeed">

<div class="content">...</div>

</div>



<div class="Row">

<input type="hidden" id="HiddenField" value="ValueINeed">

<div class="content">...</div>

</div>



<div class="Row">

<input type="hidden" id="HiddenField" value="ValueINeed">

<div class="content">...</div>

</div>
```

...

```
$('.content').widgetName( { 

            StringVal: "Test"; 

            RefVal: $(this).parents('.Row').children('#HiddenField').val()

});
```

RefVal is not setting correctly.

Comment: Seems to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/2qcCD/

Comment: @citizen conn - Thanks, but "this" isn't defined when initializing the widget, only when clicked on as per your example. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I see... maybe it should be inside some init method that gets called to instantiate the widget, so that "this" gets called only after it's been created?

Comment: I'm going to assume that semicolon in there is a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a work around in case anyone having this issue.

```
$('.content').each(function  {
    $(this).widgetName({
            StringVal: "Test",
            RefVal: $(this).parents('.Row').children('#HiddenField').val()
    });
});
```